# Conditional If Statement applied to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to iterate in a pythonic way (i.e. without a loop) through a dataframe in order to create a new columns based on whether the condition was met. In particular, given a dataframe of daily returns, I would like to create a new column that tells me whether either an upper limit or lower limit was crossed (limit is symmetric, but stock specific, so each row might have a different limit, called std in the df below) , something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)
```

That should be transformed, such that I obtain a new column which contains the respective day's return, if the upper/lower threshold was crossed, if it wasn't crossed, it should just contain the last day's return (so returns2).

```
dict2 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.05','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.3'},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'}
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2=df2.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=False)
```

I am trying to keep this flexible (so it works for more than just 2 columns with returns) and efficient (so that it works on very large dfs.

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: `dict` is a builtin data type, rather call it something else

Comment: @Tartaglia show few lines with expected result

Comment: Can you explain the columns again in df2? What is 'sl'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on df2.

```
# Make columns numeric
df2[["returns", "returns2", "std"]] = df2[["returns", "returns2", "std"]].astype(float)

# Create new column using returns2 (we'll overwrite it in . moment)
df2["output"] = df2["returns2"]
# Mask whether returns crosses std
m = df2["returns"].abs() > df2["std"]
# Overwrite that mask onto new column
df2.loc[m, "output"] = df2.loc[m, "returns"]
```

If you want to extend this to more than 2 columns then we'd need to understand the criteria for which column to select but the process would be the same: you build a mask that matches your criteria and you apply it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am still working on this...will report back

Answer (score 1):

I would use `numpy`:

```
dict1 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.05','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.3'},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2','returns2': '-0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '-0.2','returns2': '0.3','std': '0.1','sl': '-0.2'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)

ret1 = pd.to_numeric(df.returns).values
ret2 =  pd.to_numeric(df.returns2).values
std =  pd.to_numeric(df['std']).values

mask = np.abs(ret1) >= std
out = mask*ret1 + (1-mask)*ret2
print(out)
# prints [ 0.2 -0.2 -0.3 -0.2  0.2 -0.2  0.2 -0.2  0.2 -0.2  0.2 -0.2]

#then just add the column to df:
df['my_out'] = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am still working on this...will report back